# select_related(), filter() и Q() — лебедь, рак и щука? :)

Tags: django

Надо получить экземпляр класса A, по привязанным к нему экземплярам B.

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.IntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Пытаюсь делать так:

```
instances = { '1':10, '2':20, '3':30 }
for ct, id in instances.items():
qset |= Q(content_type=int(ct), object_id=int(id))
a = A.objects.all().select_related().filter(qset)
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'object_id' into field.

Если же так:

```
a_all = A.objects.all()
for a in a_all:
    print a.a_set.filter(qset)
```

То работает, но не совсем так как надо.

**Собственно вопрос: как мне получить экземпляр класса A по точному вхождению привязанных к нему экземпляров класса B?**

Comment: Вам бы заголовки в желтую прессу писать :)

Comment: Спасибо, но отчего же в жолтую? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = A.filter(b__in=queryset)
```

где `queryset` набор экземпляров `b` для поиска.

Если не так, то переформулируйте вопрос. Потому как не очень понятно.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ толкнул меня на размышления в нужном направлении.
Премного благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

После долгих размышлений, сделал так:

```
links = {}
for a in A.objects.filter(base=base):
    aid = str(a.id)
    links[aid] = []
    for ct, id in instances_kwargs.items():
        lnk = get_object_or_None(B, a=a, content_type=int(ct), object_id=int(id))
        if lnk is not None:
            links[aid].append(lnk)
        else:
            del links[aid]
            break;
```

В результате получаем все B-экземпляры, привязанные к данному A-экземпляру **строго соответствующие** входящему словарю сравнений *instances_kwargs*